# How to add Currency Switcher Drop down menu next to Add to Cart Button on Single Product page?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, themes

Hi i have this website www.gallery5designs.com and this is a link to sample product   http://gallery5designs.com/product/necklace-18k-white-gold-plating-aaa-cubic-zerconia/

I have a plugin named "WooCommerce Currency Switcher" which displays currency switching option anywhere. But the problem is that ..that plugin provide only a shortcode to embed anywhere or a widget, but i want that currency switcher  to appear net to add to cart button. I'm using child theme of Betheme for this website. can  anyone help me regarding this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code outputs the currency switcher form near add-to-cart button on single product page. However you will need to style it via css as required.
This code need to be put in your theme's/child-theme's functions.php file.

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocs_custom_location',35);
function woocs_custom_location(){
    $plugin_var= "woocommerce-currency-switcher";
    if (in_array( $plugin_var.'/index.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ){
        echo(do_shortcode('[woocs]'));
    }
}
```

I have tried and tested this with-in my woocommerce setup. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey thanks ! It worked !  can you tell me how do i make it appear next  to add to cart button ? it's showing below the button

Comment: Glad that it helped you. Can you please mark the answer as accepted (since it has atleast fullfilled your primary question? 
Regarding placing it next to add to cart button is a little challenge, as some elements in the currency switcher form have incline css.
How good are you about customizing css? Reason I am asking this is, I can suggest you accordingly. Also let me check if the inline css can be disabled by some way.

Comment: I marked the answer as accepted ! and I'm good at css ! Also to overcome the inline css we can use !important  so no problem with that also ! Just tell me what  css to add ? Also i want that currency switcher to  be the size  of  Add to cart button !

Comment: !important is used to overcome the inline css it is added like this

p { font-color: white !important ;}

Comment: > Add, {float:left; width:auto; display:inline-block} for the form containing "add-to-cart" button. css selector for same is ".woocommerce .product div.entry-summary .cart".

Comment: > Add: {float:left; width:auto;} for the currency-switcher-form. This does not have its associated css. So you will have to create new for it. You can use "form.woocommerce-currency-switcher-form" for the same.

Comment: > For div with class "product_meta", which is after "currency-switcher-form", add {clear:both}. css selector for this is ".woocommerce .product div.entry-summary .product_meta".

Comment: > Inside the currency switcher form one of the element with class "..dd-select" has inline style with {width:50%}. That you will need to set to auto. or disable. That will do the trick.

Comment: Okay let me try all that and get to you